# Find all inverse images of intervals [a,b] by Z(ω)=ω(1-ω).

Tags: probability

Find all inverse images of intervals [a,b] by Z(ω)=ω(1-ω).

I am having problems with this, if I understand correctly I have to take a<0,b<0, than a<0,b>0 and if both greater than 0?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the maximum of the function. Draw the graph and use that to deduce the  inverse image of any given interval (hint2: it is either empty, an interval or two disjoint intervals, depending on where the maximum is relative to the interval $[a,b]$)

Comment: Ok. but if I get this right maximum is at 0? because if I take any a>0,b>0 on interval [0,1]  is 0?Than i still do not get it how to find all inverse images?

Comment: No max is at $w=1/2$ and the value is $1/4$ at that point. The graph is an inverted parabola with max at $(1/2,1/4)$. So what it e.g. the inverse image of $0$? of $-1$ ? and after that, of the interval $[-1,0]$?

Comment: Yes i see now that max is at (1/2,1/4) but how do i get inverse image of 0 and -1? I am having problems with understanding concept of inverse image. I get that inverse image of f(x)=x(squered) at 4 is (-2,2) but here I am confused.

Comment: But i would say that inverse image at 0 is 0? and at -1 is empty set?

Comment: Inverse image of, say -1 consists of all solutions to the equation $Z(w)=-1$, i.e. the quadratic equation: $w(1-w)=-1$. Solve this and note that there are two real solutions  which are therefore the inverse images of $-1$ by $Z$. Try to find out for what values of $y$ there are real solutions to $Z(w)=y$. The answer has  a very close relationship with the graph of $Z$.

Comment: Ok. But then again how do I apply this to a and b? 
I understand the inverse image og let say Y(ω)=ω(squered), 
If a<0,b<0 is empty set and if a<0,b>0 is 0,b(squered).
So I have to find inverse when a,b<0 and a,b>0, right?

Comment: In this case if i understand correctly if a,b<0 inverse is empty set since working on interval (0,1)

Comment: In the statement of the problem I don't see the requirement $w\in [0,1]$? (if it is an additional requirement that we work on [0,1] then attention should be restricted to that). Anyway did you find out the number of inverse images for each value of $y$?

Comment: Yes but chapter is probability. random variables on (0,1). 
No I did not since i don't know which y to take. And since i have to work on (0,1) the only conclusion for now is that if a,b<0 inverse image is empty set.
I do not now how to proceed for other walues of a,b on interval (0,1)

Comment: Ok, more precisly show that for $y=1/4$ there is precisely one solution to $Z(w)=y$, for $y>1/4$ there are none, for $y<1/4$ there are two. But I think you have better ask someone who knows to explain graphically to you. It is difficult to transmit the information textually

Comment: Ok I understand this, but eventually what is than solution to this problem? How can I apply this to [a,b]?if a,b>1/4 is empty set, a,b=1/4 is solution to Z(w)=1/4 and a,b<1/4 two solutions? Or how can i write the solution

Comment: Case studies: For each of the cases: (1) $1/4<a<b$,   (2) $a\leq 1/4 < b$ and (3) $a < b \leq 1/4$  find the inverse images first to $a$ and $b$ and then to the interval $[a,b]$